# How to access public_html in live server?

Tags: laravel

I store all the images in laravel public/settings folder while uploading images in local.
I have now uploaded my project in live where all the public folder files are moved into the public_html.
Because of this i am facing a problem because i don't know to access the public_html in the cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Store your images in storage or resources directory.
Where it's easy to access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the directory and store them into resources/images. Your problem will be gone,

Comment: i get images from public folder in blade like assets(). So how can i get images from resources